# CloudLinux OS Node.Js Selector Error Running ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpanel, es6-modules, shared-hosting

I am trying to run my Node.js application on a Namecheap server using the Node.js Selector, but it's unable to start up because it's `require`ing the startup file

Startup file (I don't think I can just change to cjs, as my actual app is Nuxt 3. This is just an example):

```js
import http from 'http';
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var message = 'It works!\n',
        version = 'NodeJS ' + process.versions.node + '\n',
        response = [message, version].join('\n');
    res.end(response);
});
server.listen();
```

Error:

```js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:948
    throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename);
    ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/wiebdmbt/jawedding/app.mjs
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:948:11)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at startApplication (/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js:48:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Comment: I have the same error. Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the version of Node Selector installed in my "Namecheap server" didn't support ES modules. Since it was a small application (which is the only kind of application you should be running on a cheap hosting service), I was able to edit the whole app to use CommonJS modules. It was a huge waste of time though. I migrated to ES modules in the first place because I wanted to use the newest version of node-fetch only to discover that Node Selector was not compatible with the new changes. I hope you had better luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that common js can not require ES modules.

To work around this, create a `cjs` wrapper around your code by doing this:

1. Create a common js (`cjs`) file, say `myloader.cjs`.
2. Rename your 'entry file' to `.mjs`. In your case, `app.mjs`
3. Add the following piece of code to the `myloader.cjs`

```
async function loadApp() {
    await import("/path/to/app.mjs");
}

loadApp();
```

4. Change the **application startup file** in the node js setup to `myloader.cjs`.
5. Also change the `main` entry in **package.json** to `myloader.cjs`

```
"main": "myloader.cjs",
```